# How to Copy from Windows Application which doesnt support clipboard

Tags: windows, copy, clipboard

I have a windows application which has a text area but I cannot copy using Ctrl+C. The text is readable and selectable but I cannot copy it. Is there any software or addon to enable the copy to clipboard.

Comment: If it is your windows application, just enter the code and output the message into a file. After all, it is YOUR application.

Comment: It is not my application, I installed it on my machine.

Comment: If so, you don't HAVE it, you installed it. If you can not copy it, it is because the OWNER didn't want you to copy it.

Comment: when the developer is allowing me to input text in the area then why cant I copy the text which I have entered?

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on the version of windows you are using but [GetWindowText](http://www.softwareok.com/?Microsoft/GetWindowText)

can help you.

I haven't used it though.Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Clipboarder trow Desktop Gadgets. That Clipboard tracks everything you copy. Maybe you Clipboard gets cleared after coping, but with the gadget you can select it afterwords